# Смена системного стиля даты-времени в linux

Tags: linux, .net

Как поменять стиль даты-времени в `linux` с `MDY` на `DMY`? Именно системный стиль. Не просто вывести через `date` время в определенном стиле, а поменять его **полностью в системе**.
У меня есть приложение на `.NET`, которое написано именно под `DMY` и `MDY` очень сильно мешает.
Отлаживал и разрабатывал у себя на `manjaro`, все работало без проблем

Пробовал использовать `date`, но как я понял, она просто генерирует время в определенном формате, что для меня не является решением.
Пробовал переопределять формат через:

```bash
env -i LC_TIME=ru_RU.utf8 /bin/date
```

Но ничего не менялось.
Как-то "генерировал конфиги" `ru_Ru` для замены переменной `LC_TIME`, но поменялся только язык вывода

На сервере установлен `timezone МСК +03:00`

Comment: Что такое «системный стиль» и при чём тут .NET?

Comment: Системный стиль имею ввиду стиль даты, который установлен в системе: DMY - DDMMYYYY - день месяц год, MDY - MMDDYYYY - месяц день год. На сколько я понимаю, стиль даты программа берет из системы. У меня на ноутбуке переменная DateTime отображала дату в формате dd.mm.yyyy, на сервере она отображает mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: «стиль даты программа берет из системы» — почему вы так решили? Как вы получаете дату в программе и читали ли вы документацию к тому методу, с помощью которого вы получаете дату?

Comment: Если под словом «DateTime» вы имеете в виду структуру [System.DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0), то она в принципе не имеет никакого формата и вопрос по отношению к ней не имеет смысла

Comment: «стиль даты программа берет из системы» - потому что при вызове System.DateTime.ToString() на ноутбуке дата выводится в стиле dd.mm.yyyy, а при вызове того же метода на сервере выводится mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Ну вот значит открываем документацию [DateTime.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-7.0), видим там замечания про «current culture» и читаем там пример того, как подсунуть туда свой собственный [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-7.0) (и не надо пытаться выдумывать какие-то несуществующие «системные стили» в линуксе)

Comment: А почему тогда получается разный вывод одной и той же функции?

Comment: Для начала покажите вывод `locale` и `locale -a` на сервере

Comment: Всё в том же DateTime.ToString, кликнув по паре ссылок, попадаем сюда: [How a Thread's Culture Is Determined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-7.0#how-a-threads-culture-is-determined)

Comment: $ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$ locale -a
C
C.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8

Comment: Большое спасибо, поменял стандартную культуру в приложении на ru-RU и все заработало как надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LC_TIME=ru_RU.utf8 нужно передать вашей программе.

Создайте файл .sh в котором напишите

```
#!/bin/bash
export LC_TIME=ru_RU.utf8
/путь/к/вашей/программе
```

mm/dd/yy это en_US , а dd.mm.yy это русский формат

Должно сработать если приложение умеет системную локаль

Ещё нужно установить пакет locales и включить выбранные локалки.

Comment: Решил проблему вставив в начале программы строчку "CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");"
Она меняет локаль во всей программе на русскую

Comment: В вышеупомянутой мной документации написано, что .NET считывает с какого-то перепуга не LC_TIME, а LC_MESSAGES